# Can't Import Key for Pycryptodome

Tags: python, encryption

Recently, I started doing encryption and decryption in Python. I found a package called PyCryptodome, and I used the Crypto.PublicKey.RSA module. However, I can't seem to import the key in my script, but it seems to work fine in the shell. Here's my code:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, PKCS1_OAEP
from tkinter import Tk, messagebox, simpledialog

root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

priv_key_file = simpledialog.askstring('Decryption', 'Enter your private key file')
file_of_thing_to_decrypt = simpledialog.askstring('Decryption', 'Enter the file that is encrypted')
print(type(file_of_thing_to_decrypt))

try:
    file_in = open(priv_key_file, 'rb')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"Whoops! We could not find the file {priv_key_file}. Are you sure it exists?")
else:
    
    try:
        private_key = RSA.import_key(open(file_of_thing_to_decrypt, encoding='latin1').read())
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Whoops! We could not find the file {file_of_thing_to_decrypt}. Are you sure it exists?")
    else:
        enc_session_key, nonce, tag, ciphertext = [file_in.read(x) for x in (private_key.size_in_bytes(), 16, 16, -1)]
        cipher_rsa = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
        session_key = cipher_rsa.decrypt(enc_session_key)
        cipher_aes = AES.new(session_key, AES.MODE_EAX, nonce)
        data = cipher_aes.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)
        print('Hooray! We have successfully decrypted it. Here it is:')
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
        file_in.close()
```

The errors start happening where it says, `private_key = RSA.import_key(open(file_of_thing_to_decrypt, encoding='latin1').read())`
I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Brandon Code/Doors Operating System/Some Pretty Handy Encryptions/RSA ULTIMATE PACK/decoding_system.py", line 19, in <module>
    private_key = RSA.import_key(open(file_of_thing_to_decrypt, encoding='latin1').read())
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 785, in import_key
    raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")
ValueError: RSA key format is not supported
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is very confusing because the names of your file objects and they way you are using them is completely reversed. You're treating `file_of_thing_to_decrypt` as if it contains the private key and `priv_key_file` as if it contains the ciphertext. Also, what does "it seems to work fine in the shell" mean? Maybe the openssl command line? If so, then please edit your question to show the openssl command line that works.

Comment: Oh! never mind. I just accidently mixed up the variable names. Thanks for pointing that out!